Why does including twice sequentially work but doing the same thing with a loop doesn't?
I want to include the same .php file multiple times in a row, based on the length of an array.
Before I implemented that array, the code was
$value = 'something';
include 'file.php';
$value = 'other thing';
include 'file.php';

This worked perfectly fine. Now, if I do this
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_values); $i++) {
  $value = $array_values[$i];
  include 'file.php';
}

Doesn't work. It executes the first loop then stops.
I checked count($array_values) and it equals 2, I tried echoing $i before every loop and it only printed 0 (proving only the first loop happened).
I then did this:
include 'file.php';
include 'file.php';

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  include 'file.php';
}

Again, it only worked when there wasn't a loop. Why is that?
Edit: also the loop worked once I took out the include line.

What is the contents of file.php? Can you try just echo "test"; within that file?
